# How do you Make the H in Jenkins Poll SCM Schedule actually random

Tags: hash, jenkins, scheduling

I running Jenkins 1.565.1

The docs indicate the H (hash) function to be a random hash of the project name.

This does not appear to be true in my case.  I set SCM polling to be every 4 hours

```
H H/4 * * *
```

for a number of projects and they get scheduled at

```
12:00:31
12:00:58
12:00:23
12:00:14
```

This does not appear to be random at all!  Ho do I start them at a random time, and check back every 4 hours.

If I change the formula to

```
H H/3 * * *
```

or

```
H H * * *
```

It still has the same starting time, within the 12:00 minute.

Note that **this problem exists only in SCM polling**, the same schedule in "Build Periodically" behaves as documented.

Comment: From the docs: "The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project."

Comment: I realize that is the documentation, but the for the above, it does not appear to be true, according to the footnote on the configure page, which say, for example Would last have run at Thursday, October 23, 2014 12:00:05 PM CDT; would next run at Thursday, October 23, 2014 4:00:05 PM CDT.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't might losing the randomness on the hours, you could try:

```
H */4 * * *
```

which works for me.

I had to check the documentation myself, because I had used "H" only with the minutes position, but it looks like your syntax would be appropriate, actually.
The online doc provides the following examples:

```
# every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
H/15 * * * *
# once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December
H H 1,15 1-11 *
```

It might also be that the random function for your job name turns out to round at 0... Can you try renaming your job and see if you get better results ?

Comment: Jenkins does not allow this, it responds with Invalid input: "H 0/4 * * *": line 1:4: unexpected token: /

Comment: I apologize for the typo. Corrected to H */4 * * *

Comment: I also tried H */4 * * * but had the same results, only the seconds vary from job to job

Comment: Can you include your Jenkins version maybe ?