# Trigger a Jenkins Job every 2 hours at random minute in range from n to m

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, scheduled-tasks

I have a jenkins job, which I want to execute every 2 hours at random minute in range from ***n*** to ***m***.

***For example:***

```
n = 5
m = 25
```

***Expected schedule:***

```
Mar 29, 2019 2:07 PM
Mar 29, 2019 4:17 PM
Mar 29, 2019 6:13 PM
Mar 29, 2019 8:22 PM
...
```

***I have tried following:***

```
H(5-25) H/2 * * *
```

Runs every 2 hours and at 8 minutes

[image: img]

As I understood the job runs every two hours on random minute in interval between 5 and 25, but the minute is every time the same. How to force the trigger to change the minute every build in the given range?

Comment: According Jenkins documentation, _The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project_, don't believe this value. Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513386/how-do-you-make-the-h-in-jenkins-poll-scm-schedule-actually-random), maybe it helps. Btw, this schedule H(5-25) H * * * says, that you run it every hour

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Btw, this schedule H(5-25) H * * * says, that you run it every hour - You are right, edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Jenkins doesn't have such feature yet. I was able to solve this problem by adding a new `RandomWait` job with a single test, which only waits a random time. Then this job runs every 2 hours at 0 minute and after execution triggers my 'main' job.

Sample code in the `RandomJob` test:

```
public void waitRandomTime() {
    int max = 31;

    System.out.println("Peeking a random number in a range between 0 and " + (max - 1));
    int minute = new Random().nextInt(max);
    System.out.println("Start waiting " + minute + " minutes");

    for (int i = 0; i < minute; i++) {
        System.out.println("Minute: " + i);
        waitABit(60000); // wait one minute
    }
}
```

As the result I have now this job execution times:

[image: img]

***PS*** this solution is in Java, but will be similar in other languages.